# Can you please tell me the Standard value of Min,Max,Throughput and Deviation in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing

I run this test under 10 threads,10 ramp up period where my loop is 2 . I can see the avg,min,max,throughput,deviation in summery report.But how can i understand whether this report is good or bad.I mean is there any standard value for this to compare with?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpOhW.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are no "standard values" and it's **your** job to analyze the results and state whether they are "good" or "bad".

Normally there should be some [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) for the project which should define anticipated load in case of [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) which should define maximum acceptable response time or minimal acceptable throughput (number of requests per second). If the metrics you're getting within the acceptable ranges - the results are "good".

If you don't have NFRs or [SLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)  you can go for [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing), i.e. start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load at the same time looking into [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) chart. At some point you will notice that you ramping up more and more virtual users and throughput doesn't increase due to increasing response time - it will indicate the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) so you will be able to inform the project/stakeholders that the system behaves normally up to X concurrent users and after that there is performance degradation.

Going forward consider [running your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) mode with all [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) disabled as GUI mode is only for tests development and debugging and Listeners don't add any value, they only consume valuable system resources.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail explain.i appreciate it.